# Grant publish_actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I want to share some url to facebook, here is the code

```
  FB.ui(
  {
     method: 'share',
     href: "http://SomeWebPage"
  }, 
  function (response) {
  });
```

On documentation of the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) written that response data

> Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and
>   has granted **publish_actions**. If present, this is the ID of the
>   published Open Graph story.

Lets say that user not logged in to Facebook and click on  my share button
what i am see is that

The user about to login my app "Pay oneerDev"

[image: Login page]

But were exactly **publish_actions** mentioned above are defined?
How user agrees this action?

Then when user shares i get "[]" as a response data all the time instead of some id, there is no way to know if user actually shared or cancelled or some error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `publish_actions`, you would need to implement [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.4), and you would need to go through [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review) with that permission before it´s available for everyone. Just to know if something was shared or not will definitely not get that permission approved, because Share Gating is not allowed according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> 4.5: Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.

Btw, in order to make the Share Dialog work, the user just needs to login to Facebook - NOT your App. Make sure you understand the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, lets say user just logged in, can i know that the share was successful or not?

Comment: only by authorizing the user with the publish_actions permission, as you can read in the docs. there is pretty much no situation where you would need to know if the user shared something though.